# How Redirect to Other Method in one Controller with Request in laravel?

Tags: laravel

in my case i have a route for get and set API.
if user want to get something i don't want to check Validation. but if his wants to set, i Want to Check Request input validation with Request file.

look:

```
class EventsController extends Controller
{

    public function get(Request $request)
    {

        if( empty($request['data']) )
        {

          // Return Request.. is ok

        }elseif( !empty($request['data']) && $request->has('data.id') )
        {
           // so User want to insert in database and I want to check
           // Validation with Request file in the method

          // How can i Do this?
          call $this->store( // send Request to that for Validation )
        }

    }


    public function store(ValidateInput $request)
    {

        // Insert into Database

    }
}
```

Note: in the getMethod i don't want check validation but in store method i want!
1- i don't want to use other Route and i want do Both in one Request and Route
2- my main Question: who can i change Method in Controller and pass Request to that!

Comment: just make get and post with same route

Comment: The `store` method is meant to be the `set` method that you're talking about. A controller method shouldn't do both, split them into two methods. Call the `store` method directly and handle the validation there. If needed rename it to `set`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like :

```
 //Calling a method that is from the EventsController
    $result = (new EventsController)->store();
```

but the best approche is to split them into two methods as @Sandeesh said

Comment: is not work with Laravel Validation Request pass. Look Carful to My Question